# how to halt form submission in on submit event of aui script

Tags: liferay-aui

This is my aui script. After going to success part the status variable is set to `0`. But after this the condition 
`if(status == 0)` is not executed inside the block `if(starttime.length > 0 || endtime.length > 0)`.

```
  A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>addBooking').on('submit', function(event) {
    var roomIndex =A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>roomIndex").get('value');
    var bookingdate =A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>bookingdate").get('value');
    var starttime =A.one("#<portlet:names`enter code here`pace/>starttime").get('value');
    var endtime =A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>endtime").get('value');
    var status=1;
    if(starttime.length > 0 || endtime.length > 0) {
        A.io.request('${bookingValidationURL}',{
             dataType: 'json',
             method: 'POST',
             data: { <portlet:namespace/>roomIndex: roomIndex,
                 <portlet:namespace/>starttime: starttime,
                 <portlet:namespace/>endtime: endtime,
                      },
             on: {

             success: function() {

                  var data = this.get('responseData');

                  if(data==null){
                      status="0";
                  }

                }

             }

        });



 if(status==0){   // this condition is not checked when status is 0 in success part   
      event.halt();
    }   
}

});
```

Comment: Why you are assigning string like this `status="0"`, did you mean to assign integer `status=0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous.. so for doing synchronous task we have to set sync=true in ajax function...so for above code

```
  A.io.request('${bookingValidationURL}',{
         dataType: 'json',
         method: 'POST',
         sync : true, // this is the change
         data: { <portlet:namespace/>roomIndex: roomIndex,
             <portlet:namespace/>starttime: starttime,
             <portlet:namespace/>endtime: endtime,
                  },
         on: {

         success: function() {

              var data = this.get('responseData');

              if(data==null){
                  status="0";
              }

            }

         }

    });
```